# I cannot successfully compile XIB file on XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I can not successfully compile a simple Cocoa Application in XCode 3.2. Even if I make a new project Cocoa I get the same error:

```
CompileXIB ... MainMenu.xib 

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
_dispatch_get_concurrent_queue   Referenced from: /Developer/usr/bin/../../Library/Frameworks//InterfaceBuilderKit.framework/Versions/A/InterfaceBuilderKit Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _dispatch_get_concurrent_queue   Referenced from: /Developer/usr/bin/../../Library/Frameworks//InterfaceBuilderKit.framework/Versions/A/InterfaceBuilderKit Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib    Command /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 5
```

OS: MountainLion 10.8.4
XCode 3.2

How to fix this ?

Comment: Current stable versions are `macOS Big Sur 11.x` & `Xcode 12.x` respectively. Can you provide a REALLY GOOD reason to keep working on `OS: MountainLion 10.8.4 XCode 3.2`?

Comment: @TarunTyagi • perhaps Turbo C++ was unavailable.

Comment: If you're able to update to a later OS version, you should do that. If not, perhaps because of the hardware you have, you should at least update to Xcode 5.1.1, which [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_5.0_-_6.x_(since_arm64_support)) is the latest version that runs on macOS 10.8.4.

Comment: I have already installed Xcode 5, but I get many other errors... On version 3.2 it's only one

Comment: `dyld` is the dynamic linker. Error "Symbol not found" has nothing to do with the xib.